# Parsing a ReST response in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to implement a ReST request in PowerShell. Below is my $response in PowerShell.

```
@type            : bundleObject
id               : ZZZZZZ160000000000RU
orgId            : 000007
name             : xxxxxxxxxx
description      : Bundle being used for QA.
createTime       : 2015-04-24T15:13:24.000Z
updateTime       : 2015-04-24T15:13:24.000Z
createdBy        : xxx@gmail.com
updatedBy        : yyy@gmail.com
lastVersion      : 1.0
paid             : False
accessType       : PUBLIC
objects          : {@{@type=bundleRefObject; objectTypeCode=17; 
                   objectId=ZZZZZZ17000000000003; 
                   objectName=Mapping_01; objectDescription=; 
                   objectUpdateTime=2015-04-24T15:05:41.000Z}, 
                   @{@type=bundleRefObject; objectTypeCode=17; 
                   objectId=ZZZZZZ17000000000004; 
                   objectName=Mapping_02; objectDescription=; 
                   objectUpdateTime=2015-04-24T15:09:28.000Z}, 
                   @{@type=bundleRefObject; objectTypeCode=17; 
                   objectId=ZZZZZZ17000000000005; 
                   objectName=Mapping_03; objectDescription=; 
                   objectUpdateTime=2015-04-24T15:11:59.000Z}}
externalId       : CYIhYNVCSdC6J17N-LyA6A
```

In the objects section, there are 3 object ids. I need to copy these ids & names in a list, for later use. I have successfully fetched the objects part using

```
$responseobject = $response.objects
```

However, I am unsure how I can fetch the object name & object ids and save in a list. Should I use a PSCustomObject here?

--------------------------Updated

One more query here. I added the values to a hashmap with

```
$response_connection_hashmap = $response_connection|foreach {
    @{  $_.name = $_.id }
    }
```

However, while fetching values with key

```
$response_connection_hashmap.Item('Key_1')
```

I am getting error as

```
Exception getting "Item": "Cannot convert argument "index", with value:  "Key_1", for "get_Item" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "Key_1" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correctformat.
```

am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how you intend to use the values.

If the only thing you need is an array of IDs, you can use

```
($response.objects).objectIds
```

or, in longer form (necessary for older versions of PS)

```
$response.objects | Select-Object -ExpandProperty objectIds
```

If you need to pull out the values to operate on them one by one, you can use `foreach` to iterate over the objects.

```
$response.objects | foreach {
  Do-SomethingWith -id $_.objectID -updateTime $_.objectUpdateTime
}
```

If you need (for further processing) a variable containing the ID and UpdateTime for all of the objects, then you can build an array of hashmaps:

```
$responseObjectList = $response.objects | foreach {
  @{ id = $_.objectID; updateTime = $_.objectUpdateTime }
}
```

Or `PSCustomObject`s, if you want them to print nicely.

```
$responseObjectList = $response.objects | foreach {
  [PSCustomObject]@{ id = $_.objectID; updateTime = $_.objectUpdateTime }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was helpful!! I intend to use the id value in further ReST calls. Hash map normally contains a key-value pairs. But in my case I need an array containing a list of single value, such as id or name, so that it would be easier to parsing the array and for each element call a rest request using id as variable

Comment: If all you want is an array of ID values, it's as simple as `($response.objects).objectId`

Comment: Oh ok! That was pretty straight forward!! Thanks for helping out!!